# How to type partially known interface keys in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface with 1 unknown key and 1 known key and different types. Can can I type this?

```js
interface Props {
  onChange: (event) => void;
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

I will *always* have `onChange` and the other key, a `data` key, is *always* a string with an unknown name.

**Edit:**
Including more of the example. I'm writing a wrapper that changes the `onChange` prop in a React component and passes the remaining props along.

```js
const ComponentWithHiddenInput = (component: React.FC, dataKey: string) => {
  return (props) => {
    const { [dataKey]: defaultValue, onChange: name } = props;
    const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
    return (
      <>
        <input name={name} type="hidden" ref={inputRef} defaultValue={defaultValue} />
        {component({ ...props, onChange: setHiddenInput(inputRef.current) })}
      </>
    );
  };
};
```

I'm struggling to type the `props` attribute. I'd like to specify `onChange`, say `dataKey` is a string version that gets assigned to the value, and all other props don't matter because they're passed along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really - using computed properties in types is pretty risky because they tend to be way too permissive, allowing just about any number of valid keys to be added as long as they satisfy the computed property constraint (which is not very constrained!)

It seems pretty unlikely that your second key name will literally *always* be unknown -- it seems like at some point somewhere, you'll have to define an actual key with a string value to be used somehow. Otherwise there isn't even a point to typing this, you'd get no benefit. If that is the case, a better option would be to use generics to constrain the second key you want to have. Something like this:

```
type Props<K extends string> = {
  onChange: (event: any) => void;
} & {
  [key in K]: string;
}
```

Then you can use it like so, essentially creating a new type with the key you want:

```
type MyPropsWithFoo = Props<"foo">;
```

This plays relatively nicely with React components too, although I couldn't get it to infer the value of the key from usage, I had to define it explicitly:

```
function MyComponent<K extends string>(props: Props<K>) {
    return null;
}

function App() {
    return <MyComponent<'foo'> foo={'bar'} onChange={() => {}} />
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgAUcwBnAHgGk4kAPGJAHYATFnBYwowAQHMAfHAC8cAN7k4cCAIDCACxQykALjgAKJADdBMY-uoBKRfPMRgQigF84AMhVq4AbQBrJGo4KVMuXn5hUXxNXX1pJHw4AH44AQskKDhjDjsAXWNxSRkPSho6OABZaiYIVgB1YBgdADEICEVGZnYAIkxOvtkKAHpR9TgAPVTKTABXAQxgTRrqLVxITIEYTm4%20QRExCSk5EzBe43rWTlkHVUm4cYyIfjhWlHhqCHm4AHdNPh4HpLHB0GgkCxRDAugMhhocn89PxLDlWvQLg1sjQwqIdNkkAAaMRdFr4UQCV5wIgoAA2tNCqNC8xYSAWtPeXRB9HRrPetFOLD86iIMHmUAEGXm9PK5AWSxgK0lAEEwGATPdhdSkGKJXA2LUNuBNFY2PhBhB8PILQplPgAEYoKD4TzxPQGW0axwqdyeUaycjuchAA)

This kinda works, but come to think of it doesn't actually do anything useful for you. `<MyComponent>` will never be able to directly access `"foo"` or whatever the wildcard key you're trying to pass into it - the function literally has no way to know what property name to expect, without more strict constraints. So, what exactly is the point of having a "wildcard" property name on an object, that no function or logic will be able to access or interact with?

It's hard to say what would work best in your case without more details, so perhaps you can update your answer with more context.

Comment: Yeah, the second property doesn't actually do anything. I'm trying to pass it along. I only care about `onChange`. I updated the question to include more of the example.

You're right -- there's not value in typing these things, but I don't want to leave it open as `any` :/

Comment: Maybe I'm looking for sort of the opposite of `Partial<Props>`. These 2 fields exist on the object and the others are unknown.

Comment: Ah it sounds like what you're trying to do is a higher order component. In that case try reading into that route, e.g. here is an article: https://medium.com/@jrwebdev/react-higher-order-component-patterns-in-typescript-42278f7590fb